# Maximum number of contacts Gazebo ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where and how can we set maximum number of contacts in Gazebo?

By default the max. num. of contacts is 20  "rosparam get /gazebo/max_contacts"
Setting the parameter to any other ( ex. 100) " rosparam set /gazebo/max_contacts 100 "
does not affect the simulation results, I am always getting 20 contacts using gazebo plugin
bumpers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206319/maximum-number-of-contacts-gazebo-ros/) by [Nomad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19317/nomad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nomad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19317/nomad/) on 2015-04-06**:
Calling service rosservice call /gazebo/setphysicsproperties and setting maxcontacts to 100 does not work. After calling service rosservice call /gazebo/getphysicsproperties the maxcontacts is still 20.

**Comment by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) on 2015-04-08**:
in https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e01e520d15603b87efaffa26817bf6224f00f320/gazebo/physics/Contact.hh?at=gazebo_2.2

```
#define MAX_CONTACT_JOINTS 32
```

might be one reason which limits the number of contacts generated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think gazebo would react to a service call, not to a parameter change on the parameter server

maybe try using the

```
rosservice call /gazebo/set_physics_properties
```

and copy the current properties that you get with

```
rosservice call /gazebo/get_physics_properties
```

something like

```
rosservice call /gazebo/set_physics_properties "time_step: 0.001
max_update_rate: 1000.0
gravity: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
ode_config: 
  auto_disable_bodies: False
  sor_pgs_precon_iters: 0
  sor_pgs_iters: 50
  sor_pgs_w: 1.3
  sor_pgs_rms_error_tol: 0.0
  contact_surface_layer: 0.001
  contact_max_correcting_vel: 100.0
  cfm: 0.0
  erp: 0.2
  max_contacts: 100"
```

---

Originally posted by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) with karma: 242 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nomad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19317/nomad/) on 2015-04-01**:
@guiHome the objects in Gazebo freeze after calling this service. However in RVIZ, I see that frames move and  there even collisions. It seems that simulation is working but the visualization in Gazebo fails. The maximum number of contacts is still 20.

**Comment by [GuiHome](https://answers.ros.org/users/768/guihome/) on 2015-04-08**:
my suggested parameters have no gravity and settings that work on my side. You should copy the settings that worked for you using the get_physics_properties
I double checked and indeed the maximum contact does not change after setting it